# Problems with simultaneous couchbase clients towards the same couchbase server

Tags: .net, client, couchbase

I know the recommendation from couchbase is to create one single instance of a couchbase client, and reuse that throughout your application. But in my case, there woukd be much easier to create several because they might connect to several different couchbase servers and the time usage on creating the instance is not a factor in this case. However, it seems that creating two instances towards the same server fails. Consider the following code:

```
var section = (CouchbaseClientSection)<Section of configuration read from web.config>;
var client1 = new CouchbaseClient(section);
//a call to fetch data from client1 here succeeds just fine
var client2 = new CouchbaseClient(section);
//a call to fetch data from client2 here fails with the following message:
//{"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."}
```

With a slight modification, and disposing the first client before creating the second one, it works just fine:

```
var section = (CouchbaseClientSection)<Section of configuration read from web.config>;
var client1 = new CouchbaseClient(section);
//a call to fetch data from client1 here succeeds just fine
client1.Dispose();
var client2 = new CouchbaseClient(section);
//a call to fetch data from client2 here succeeds just fine
```

Secondly, if client2 is pointing towards another coiuchbase instance, it also works fine:

```
var section1 = (CouchbaseClientSection)<Section of configuration read from web.config>;
var section2 = (CouchbaseClientSection)<Another section of configuration read from web.config>;
var client1 = new CouchbaseClient(section1);
//a call to fetch data from client1 here succeeds just fine
var client2 = new CouchbaseClient(section2);
//a call to fetch data from client2 here succeeds just fine
```

So it only fails if there are two active connections open towards the same couchbase instance at the same time, but I have found nothing inside the couchbase documentation that indicates that this is a problem. **Why does the first example fail?**

Have anyone had the same problem as me? Could there be some settings somewhere that needs to be changed to allow this?

Comment: I don't know about current version of library, but in previous version s (may be 1.2.1) I've successfully created multiple client instances to same bucket (actually that was my mistake, because I've created one client instance per object - client init was in object constructor), but it worked. Now may be developers added some kind of foolproof check to prevent people like me from doing such things.

Answer (score 0):

This works AFAIK using the 1.3.0 version of the client:

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("couchbase") as CouchbaseClientSection;

var client1 = new CouchbaseClient(section);
var result1 = client1.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, "xxxfnkey1", "xxxfnvalue1");
Console.WriteLine("Result1: {0} {1}", result1.Success, result1.Message);

var getResult1 = client1.ExecuteGet("xxxfnkey1");
Console.WriteLine("getResult1: {0} {1}", getResult1.Success, getResult1.Message);

var client2 = new CouchbaseClient(section);
var result2 = client2.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, "xxxfnkey2", "xxxfnvalue2");
Console.WriteLine("Result2: {0} {1}", result2.Success, result2.Message);

var getResult2 = client2.ExecuteGet("xxxfnkey2");
Console.WriteLine("getResult2: {0} {1}", getResult2.Success, getResult2.Message);
```

If it's not working for you, it could possibly be an issue with your configuration. The client itself definitely supports multiple instances being created from a single configuration section.